# Bureau human computing services

Tags: computation

Prior to the development of electronic computers, human computers were used and computer departments consisted of a room with humans at desks performing calculations.

Large scientific organizations, such as Nasa and [Los Alamos Laboratories](https://ttps://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5616/day-to-day-tasks-of-human-computers-%C3%A0-la-hidden-figures-movie) and [Gilbert Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_Walker_(physicist)) in India in the early 1900s, when he utilized

> a group of Indian clerks to calculate correlations between weather parameters

that lead to the discovery of the [Southern Oscillation Index](https://www.climate.gov/news-features/understanding-climate/climate-variability-southern-oscillation-index), all utilized in house human computers.

Were there external organizations, anywhere, that offered computing services for a fee or were computers employed in house or hired for specific projects?

Comment: See [Hidden Figures (book)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Figures_(book)) and related movie and see [Computer (occupation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_computer#Origins_in_sciences) and [Harvard Computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_Computers).

Comment: Yes, there were such computer centers which just performed computations for a fee. They are mentioned in the early 20th century literature, even in fiction.